# Net Core 2: Cannot inherit from KeyNotFoundException

Tags: .net-core, nuget

I have something weird:

I had a class like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
namespace My.Client
{
    public class XNotFoundException : KeyNotFoundException
    {
        public XFoundException(string s, Exception e) : base(s, e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

This class is published via nuget package which contains Refit 4.3.0 and AspNetCore.All 2.0.6.

A project which references this package tries to use the class.. but the build cannot find the class. Other classes from this package work just fine.  The error they receive is:

> CS0246: The type or namespace name 'XNotFoundException' could not be
>   found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

If I inherit from Exception instead of KeyNotFoundException, it "works". But why? Is there some complication that I missed?

Comment: What's the exact error you are getting from the build system?

Comment: @JohnKoerner The error is:  error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'XNotFoundException' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Is the target framework for the nuget package .net core 2.0 or .net standard 2.0, or something else?